# Program new functionality for zoom button on Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Desktop 7000

Tags: c#, python, keyboard, driver

I just bought a new keyboard and mouse (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Desktop 7000) and it has a neat little zoom lever in the middle of the keyboard. What I'd like to do is write a little program (in C# or Python, for use on Windows Vista) which makes the zoom button act like a scroll button instead.

I have no idea where to start. Where do I start? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web page en comments should help you out a bit: [Icool blog](http://oliiscool.blogspot.com/2006/11/hacking-microsoft-natural-ergonomic.html)